# I am able to use StateObject in ios 13. Is that a bug or is it real?

Tags: swiftui

StateObject

In the past, StateObject was only available in ios 14, but all of a sudden I can use it in ios 13.

However, I can't find anywhere that StateObject is available in ios 13. Even when I go to its definition, it says ios 14.

I am using xcode 13.2

Comment: Have you tested this on a device running iOS 13? As I think this is dependent on the device/simulator you are building on to. If your building onto an iOS 15 device then it will work but if you build it on to an iOS 13 device it will crash

Comment: Good idea i m going to try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update February 19th 2023

This appears to now be fixed in Xcode 14.3 Beta 1. When adding `@StateObject` a compilation error now occurs and a warning is displayed in Xcode stating:

> 'StateObject' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer.
>
> Add @available attribute to enclosing struct

[image]

## Update July 14th 2022

I have checked to see if this is still occurring on Xcode 14 Beta 3 and unfortunately it is.

I have updated my feedback to Apple stating this.

## Update June 28th 2022

Apple replied to my feedback that I submitted for this issue, asking if it still occurs while using Xcode 14 Beta 2, the unfortunate answer is yes. The issue is still occurring.

I have updated my feedback with the additional information they requested and hopefully they will be able to fix the lack of error produced when using `StateObject` in an iOS 13 project.

## Original Answer Dec 2021

I think that this is a bug in the compiler.

Taking a very simple example application:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    init() {}
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

With the `Targets` Deployment target set to 13.0

[image]

and the `Projects` Deployment target also set to 13.0

[image]

If I build for an iPhone 13 on iOS 15 the application compiles and builds without a warning, and runs without issue.

However, if I build for an iPhone 6S on iOS 13 the application compiles and builds without a warning but when it runs it produces the following error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI11StateObjectV12wrappedValueACyxGxyXA_tcfC
  Referenced from: /Users/andrew/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F12BA8CD-671F-4EA2-94E4-784DA2EE1A1C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0A6FA610-FF19-47EB-A062-4AA7A296F464/Thirteen.app/Thirteen
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI

dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI11StateObjectV12wrappedValueACyxGxyXA_tcfC
  Referenced from: /Users/andrew/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F12BA8CD-671F-4EA2-94E4-784DA2EE1A1C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0A6FA610-FF19-47EB-A062-4AA7A296F464/Thirteen.app/Thirteen
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI

CoreSimulator 783.5 - Device: iPhone 6s (F12BA8CD-671F-4EA2-94E4-784DA2EE1A1C) - Runtime: iOS 13.0 (17A577) - DeviceType: iPhone 6s
```

And highlights the problem in Xcode

[image]

I would expect that the application should not compile and build if it is using an API that is only available for a newer SDK.

Comment: I was hoping this is real, yeah it's a bug

Comment: Possible solutions may found at -  https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/atstateobject-on-ios-13/6655

Comment: The solution is not to use ObservedObject as that is not the issue, the issue is that the compiler should throw an error when you try to use something that is not compatible with the targeted iOS version. The application should not compile and run, and then crash because something is missing.

Comment: In case anyone comes across this. You can find a fully functional backport of this (and more) in my backports library. 

https://gitHub.com/shaps80/SwiftUIBackports